# bound of Erlang distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, approximation, random

Is there any known polynomial bound of the Erlang distribution? I'd like to say that, given $k$ and $\lambda$ with probability p the r.v. is going to be less than some value x.

Comment: Let $X_k \sim \mathrm{Erlang}(k,\lambda)$. Then $\mathbb P(X_k \leq t) = \mathbb P(N(t,\lambda) \geq k)$ where $N(t,\lambda) \sim \mathrm{Pois}(\lambda t)$. Now you can use your favorite tail bound on the Poisson distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is simply the cumulative distribution function, [given in WP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_distribution#Cumulative_Distribution_Function_.28CDF.29) by $\gamma(k,k\lambda)/(k-1)! = 1-\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}\mathrm e^{-\lambda x}(\lambda x)^{n}/n! $, where $\gamma$ is the incomplete gamma function.

Comment: I know, but I wanted to see if there is an approximation that does not involve factorials

Comment: Why that constraint? If $k$ is large, you can use [Stirling approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_approximation). There are probably approximations for the incomplete gamma function too.